# What is the meaning of this .gitconfig filesystem section? [filesystem "Private Build|1.8.0_222|/home/user/.Private"]

Tags: git, config

I found the following section in my global `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[filesystem "Private Build|1.8.0_222|/home/user/.Private"]
    timestampResolution = 1001 microseconds
    minRacyThreshold = 6142 microseconds
```

I searched for the `filesystem` section or any supported section names that are allowed within the `.gitconfig`, but I could not find anything.
It is somehow related to the fact that my home directory/partition is encrypted.

The new section was added within the last week during some updates:

```
 ~ stat .gitconfig 
[...]
Access: 2019-09-23 09:31:26.281891326 +0200
Modify: 2019-09-19 11:47:45.849899707 +0200
Change: 2019-09-19 11:47:45.849899707 +0200
 Birth: -
```

**Versions**

- **git**: 2.17.1
- **OS**: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- **libecryptfs1**: 111-0ubuntu5

Comment: That is jgit, which for some reasons thinks that it is a good idea to persist data in a user configuration file. Related bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551850

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This comes from JGit (are you using Eclipse 2019-09?). The [release notes for 5.1.9](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.jgit/releases/5.1.9) have some more information about this along with pointers to related tickets.

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest eclipse version but not the build in git solution except from importing projects from git inot my workspace.
I use the git cli for dealing with git.
Thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

The jgit code needs to persist that data somewhere, and for a while it would store it in the user `~/.gitconfig` file.

But you can control where jgit stores this information using the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable, as documented in [this jgit commit](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/commit/?id=838b5a84b5093c335b95a644b8888006d9e95493).

For example if you use `gradle` to run tests that use `jgit`, you can use:

```
test {
    environment "XDG_CONFIG_HOME", buildDir
}
```